# Detect Collision Between Two UIImageViews & Ignore Transparent Parts

Tags: ios, uiimageview, collision

I have a rectangle and some circles (UIImageViews) and I want to check if they are colliding.

It works fine when they collide like this (using CGRectIntersectsRect) it works fine:

[image: working]

But when they collide diagonally, it doesn't work like I want it to, this is considered a collision:

[image: not working]

So I was wondering if there is a way to ignore the transparent areas when colliding and preferably not pixel to pixel checks because I have a lot of these and it may affect performance.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I've done a lot of research on this and cannot find anything that actually says what to do. Most people say "do research." If someone could actually give me a link or help me do this (with Sprite Kit or anything), that would be great.